# SimpleMembership MVC3 Could not load file or assembly WebMatrix.Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, simplemembership

I'm using the SimpleMembership.MVC3 package to manage membership. Everything works fine at development but when I deploy to my Azure web role, It throws the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> stack trace: [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw
>   an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +11711966
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +465
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1167
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw
>   an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11700896
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +141    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4869125

There's no WebMatrix.Data assembly downloaded when I install the Nuget Package. 
I've manually added the WeBMatrix.Data.DLL found at my Program Files/Microsoft ASP.NET directory, but the version of this assembly is 2.x, and the one missing is version 1.x

What is missing?

Comment: I solved using a bindingredirect to version 2.x

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue. I right-clicked on the Reference in the Project and went to Properties. Change the CopyToLocal setting from True to False and rebuilt the project. Resolved my issue.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just had the same results (i.e. fixed the problem) by flipping it from False to True. In my case using VS2013 and MVC5.

Comment: I had to do the opposite... Changed the value from False to True.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the Reference from Nuget instead of the local reference. This solved my issue.

Here is the package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.Data/