# MVC4 app works in development, but not when deployed due to missing assembly WebMatrix.Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

So, I have an MVC4 app that works fine in Visual Studio 2012/IIS Express. I tried publishing it to a local folder, and then creating a site in regular IIS on another machine--to test the deployment. I'm getting an error that the WebMatrix.Data assembly is missing, but there's no such reference in my project. Now, there is WebMatrix.WebData, but no WebMatrix.Data. Incidentally, I have WebMatrix.WebData with CopyLocal = true.

Per a suggestion from this question, I tried setting CopyLocal = false on the WebMatrix.WebData reference. [SimpleMembership MVC3 Could not load file or assembly WebMatrix.Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762125/simplemembership-mvc3-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webmatrix-data)

But after doing this, I get an "access is denied" error (HTTP 401.2: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe WebMatrix.WebData has a dependency on WebMatrix.Data? Is there a WebMatrix.Data.dll in your bin folder on your development machine?

Comment: thanks for response. There's no WebMatrix dll of any flavor in the bin folder in development. And btw, the 401.2 error was because I forgot to turn on Windows authentication in IIS for this project.